# How to load XBRL data to Elasticsearch through logstash

Tags: logstash

```
- <!--Cost of Revenues -->
<group type="ci:grossProfit.costOfGoodsAndServicesSold">
- <group type="ci:costOfGoodsAndServicesSold.costOfGoodsSold">
<label href="xpointer(..)" xml:lang="en">License</label>
<item id="IS-010" period="P1Y/1999-05-31">19355</item>
<item id="IS-011" period="P1Y/1998-05-31">11220</item>
<item id="IS-012" period="P1Y/1997-05-31">6362</item>
</group>
- <group type="ci:costOfGoodsAndServicesSold.costOfServices">
<label href="xpointer(..)" xml:lang="en">Service</label>
<item id="IS-013" period="P1Y/1999-05-31">18350</item>
<item id="IS-014" period="P1Y/1998-05-31">11118</item>
<item id="IS-015" period="P1Y/1997-05-31">8260</item>
</group>
<label href="xpointer(..)" xml:lang="en">Total cost of revenues</label>
<item id="IS-016" period="P1Y/1999-05-31">37705</item>
<item id="IS-017" period="P1Y/1998-05-31">22338</item>
<item id="IS-018" period="P1Y/1997-05-31">14622</item>
</group>
- <!-- Gross profit -->
- <group type="ci:operatingProfit.grossProfit">
<label href="xpointer(..)" xml:lang="en">Gross profit</label>
<item id="IS-019" period="P1Y/1999-05-31">97202</item>
<item id="IS-020" period="P1Y/1998-05-31">63321</item>
<item id="IS-021" period="P1Y/1997-05-31">42498</item>
</group>
<!-- Operating expenses -->
- <group type="ci:operatingProfit.operatingExpenses">
- <group           type="ci:sellingGeneralAndAdministrativeExpenses.sellingAndMarketingExpenses">
<label href="xpointer(..)" xml:lang="en">Sales and marketing</label>
<item id="IS-022" period="P1Y/1999-05-31">47982</item>
<item id="IS-023" period="P1Y/1998-05-31">31636</item>
<item id="IS-024" period="P1Y/1997-05-31">21935</item>
</group>
```

Loading XBRL data to Elasticsearch through logstash. Above mentioned data is my XBRL test data.
Facing difficulties while configuring logstash config file.
Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do => What data do you want to extract, which format do you wish to have ? What have you tried so far? Did it work? If not, what happened?

Comment: Actually It is a XBRL file of a financial company. I want to parse data  through Logstash in the given specified format(json)- {"License":19355,"Service":18350,"Total cost of revenues":37705,"Gross profit":97202,"Sales and marketing":47982}.
All data is coming under "message" field. Pls help me to configure this data.

Comment: Could you explain (in your question) how you the data is supposed to be transformed into the specified format?

Comment: But it seems to me it might be a little too complicated for Logstash and it should be done with a specific program equipped with an xml parser.

Comment: I have tried with xml parser but I did not get any output.

Comment: Did you try with the logstash xml filter plugin? If yes, could you add your configuration to the question? If not, you should ask another question about your parser (if you wish to go with an xml parser).